# how to find the tangent space to $f(\mathbb{R})$ where $f$ is defined by $t \mapsto (\cos t,\sin t,t)$?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ defined by $f(t) = (\cos t,\sin t,t)$

first as a hint it was suggested to show that $f : \mathbb{R} \to f(\mathbb{R})$ is a homeomorphism. (I have no idea how this will be helpful afterwards)

so clearly when restrained to $f(\mathbb{R})$ the map is surjective.

also $\text{dim} (\mathbb{R})  = 1 = \text{dim}(\text{Ker}f) + \text{rk} f$

because $f$ is surjective $ \iff \text{rk} f = 1$ then it follows that $\text{dim}(\text{Ker}f) = 0 \iff $ f is injective

the inverse $f^{-1}(t) = (\arccos t, \arcsin t, t)$ is continuous therefore $f$ is a homeomorphism, right ?

now how to find $T_{f(\mathbb{R})}(x_0)$ ? I know that $f(\mathbb{R})$ is an helix ?

I tried to write $f(\mathbb{R})$ as $\{(x,y,z) \;|\; x^2+y^2 = 1, z = \frac 12(\arccos x + \arcsin y)\}$

then considered the mapping $g(x,y,z) = (x^2+y^2 - 1, z - \frac 12(\arccos x + \arcsin y))$

$f(\mathbb{R}) = g^{-1}({0})$

$dg(x,y,z) = \begin{bmatrix}
2x & 2y & 0 \\
\frac {1}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}} &-\frac {1}{2\sqrt{1-y^2}} & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

which has rank $2$ whenever $x,y \neq 0 $

I hoped that it would be a submersion so I can construct the tangent space just from the Kernel but it wasn't.

Any help, hints will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes no sense the use apply the rank-nullity theorem to a non-linear map.

The tangent space to $f(\mathbb{R})$ at some point $f(t_0)$ is the line$$\left\{f(t_0)+\lambda f'(t_0)\,\middle|\,\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\right\}=\left\{\left(\cos t_0,\sin t_0,t_0\right)+\lambda\left(-\sin t_0,\cos t_0,1\right)\,\middle|\,\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\right\}.$$